# How to filter and calculate same object array value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

For example i have this object array

```
const purchases = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  }
]
```

How can i effectively filter and calculate by purchases.name, create the output can be like this

```
let filteredPurchases = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 1500  
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 1000  
  }
]
```

Comment: i've tried code & search related question, mdn, but i don't want to share my fail code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()`, group your data based on `name` value and add `price` for same `name` in an object and then extract out all the values.

```js
const purchases = [ { name: 'a', price: 500 }, { name: 'a', price: 1000 }, { name: 'b', price: 500 }, { name: 'b', price: 500 } ],
      result = Object.values(purchases.reduce((r,{name, price}) => {
        r[name] = r[name] || {name, price : 0};
        r[name].price += price;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and an object reference for keeping the index.

```js
const purchases = [{
    name: 'a',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  }
];

// object for keeping index
const ref = Object.create(null);

let res = purchases
  // iterate over the array
  .reduce((arr, o) => {
    // check index already defined, if defined add price value
    if (o.name in ref) arr[ref[o.name]].price += o.price;
    // if not then define index and insert a new object with all property of object
    else arr[ref[o.name] = arr.length] = Object.assign({}, o);
    // return the array reference
    return arr;
    // set initial value as an array for result
  }, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const purchases = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  }
];
var result = []
function findSum(array, key) {
  let sum = 0;
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    if(key == element.name) {
      sum = sum + element.price;
    }   
  });
  return sum;
}
purchases.forEach(function(element) { 
  let sum = findSum(purchases, element.name);       
  result[element.name] =({name:element.name,price:sum});   
});
console.log("Result obj")
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and intermediate map to sum the price of the items, and then iterate through it to create the desired result:

```js
const purchases = [{
    name: 'a',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'a',
    price: 1000
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    price: 500
  }
];

const mapped = purchases.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (!result[item.name]) {
    result[item.name] = item.price;
  } else {
    result[item.name] = result[item.name] + item.price;
  }
  return result;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(mapped).map(key => {
  return {
    name: key,
    price: mapped[key]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```